# How to use ScalaTest "contain allOf" on two lists?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I was looking for a ScalaTest matcher to check that a list contains all of the needed elements (given within another list), but that may also be others.

`contain allOf` demands to get two fixed elements, for some reason, the rest as varargs.

I can do a workaround like this, but it's tremendously ugly:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
val wanted = List(1,2,3)
list should contain allOf ( wanted.head, wanted.tail.head, wanted.tail.tail  :_* )    // ugly workaround
```

For giving a list as the match, there is `contain theSameElementsAs`. However, it does not allow extraneous elements to be in the probed value (I think).

So:

- am I missing something?
- why is `allOf` declared in the way that it must be given two fixed elements in the front (i.e. why not just pass varargs?)
- should there be `theSameElementsAndMaybeMoreThan`method (presumably with a better name)?

Some code I tried with:

```
val list = List.empty[String]
//list should contain allOf("a")         // does not compile
list should contain allOf("a","b")
list should contain allOf("a","b","c")

val wanted = List("a","b","c")
//list should contain allOf( wanted )    // does not compile
list should contain allOf( wanted.head, wanted.tail )   // compiles, but tests the wrong thing; against List(head,List(tail))
```

[documentation](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/#org.scalatest.Matchers@workingWithContainers):

Scala 2.11.4, ScalaTest 2.2.1

**Edit:**

I probably end up using something like:

```
wanted.foreach( list should contain(_) )
```

However, this does not seem as readable to me (the `should` is kind of embedded) as the built-in collection constructs.

Comment: Have you considered using Sets?

```Set(1, 4).subsetOf(Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))```

Comment: It kind of makes sense because it's not designed to work with lists but with items. Why it's 2 arguments and a vararg after that? Probably because if you want to give it less than 2, it won't be `allOf` anymore, it will be just `contain`.

Comment: @AnasAlkhatib No, I didn't consider sets, but conceptually that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari Yes, that's similar to how I figured as to why the minimum was 2 params. It makes sense. I wasn't sure (still am not) whether it's really an API omission, so I turned to SO for ideas. And again, got two great ones.

Comment: @AnasAlkhatib With your suggestion, I must use an `assert` instead of `should` matchers, right? I'd like to use matchers for the tests.

Comment: You can always use `Set().subsetOf(Set()) shouldBe true`, but you lose the information about what went wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bill Venners had this to say on the ScalaTest mailing list:

> Yes, we didn't want to hold up the 2.0 release to add that, but have
>   since added it. I believe we added it to master, though, not the 2.2.x
>   branch. Regardless, the syntax looks like:

`xSet should contain allElementsOf (ySet)`

Link to the [message](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/scalatest-users/SyyW8RC1pfA).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any good reason for this.  You can remedy this with a pimp my class:

```
object ScalaTestUtils {
    import org.scalatest.words.ResultOfContainWord

    implicit class ResultOfContainWordImprovements[T](val contains: ResultOfContainWord[Seq[T]]) {
        def allOf(right: Seq[T]) = contains allOf(right.head, right.tail.head, right.tail.tail :_*)
    }
}
```

You should probably make this account for `Seqs` with fewer than 2 elements (for which this would fail).

Then, you can do:

```
import ScalaTestUtils._
Seq(1, 2, 3) should contain allOf Seq(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is:

```
import org.scalatest.Inspectors.forAll

forAll(list) { wanted should contain(_) }
```

Expect an error message similar to this:

```
scala> forAll(List(1, 2)) { List(1) should contain(_) }
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: forAll failed, because:
  at index 1, List(1) did not contain element 2 (<console>:18)
in List(1, 2)
...
Caused by: org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: List(1) did not contain element 2
```

Comment: Looks reasonable. However, ScalaTest seems to have released 3.0.0 so I presume the `should contain allElementsOf` that Bill mentions is there. Haven't checked, or needed it recently.