# ScalaTest matcher syntax for checking whether one collection contains the elements of another

Tags: scala, scalatest

In ScalaTest it's easy to check whether a container has certain elements:

```
val theList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
theList should contain allOf(5, 3, 1) // passes
```

However, if you already have a list containing those elements you want to check for, it's not obvious how to make use of it. The code below doesn't compile, because `allOf()` only takes collection elements, not collections, and expects at least two of them.

```
val theList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val expected = List(5, 3, 1)
theList should contain allOf(expected) // doesn't compile
```

Since a Scala `List` doesn't have `containsAll()`, you can't even do this:

```
val theList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
theList.containsAll(expected) should be(true) // doesn't compile
```

Right now I'm doing the following, but I'm not happy with it:

```
for(x <- expected) {
  theList should contain(x)
}
```

Is there a more fluent / Scala-ish / standard way to make this assertion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801679/how-to-use-scalatest-contain-allof-on-two-lists/26808095?iemail=1&noredirect=1#26808095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use implicit classes to add missing method

```
trait AllElementsOf {
  implicit class AllElementsOf[L <: GenTraversable[_]](resultOfContainWord: ResultOfContainWord[L]) {
    def allElementsOf(l: L)(implicit aggregating: Aggregating[L]) = {
      val list = l.toList
      assume(list.size >= 2, s"Expected to see list longer than 2")
      resultOfContainWord.allOf(list(0), list(1), list.drop(2):_*)
    }
  }

}

class AllOfListSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers with AllElementsOf {

  "list" should "contain all of another list" in {
    val theList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val expected = List(5, 3, 1)
    theList should contain allElementsOf expected
  }
}
```

**Update**

*Official* allElementsOf will be in scalatest 3.0