# scalatest using contains allElementsOf with ArrayBuffers

Tags: xml, scala, contains, scalatest

I have been working with some XML data and have been trying to write a test that tries to match that the direct children of two xml trees have all the same nodes of type `bar`.

I started off using a simple test to ensure that both data structures match.

The assertion matching them as strings works:

```
result.toString should be(expected.toString)
```

but the assertion matching each individual element fails:

```
result should contain allElementsOf expected
```

which I found on this **[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801679/how-to-use-scalatest-contain-allof-on-two-lists)**

because these simpler assertion did not work:

```
result should be(expected)
result should contain(expected(1))
```

The test sets up the XML using `before` block in the test class:

```
  var foo: Elem = _

  before {
   foo = <foo>
     <bar type="greet" style="pleasent" target="anyone">hi</bar>
     <bar type="count">1</bar>
     <bar type="color">yellow</bar>
     <baz>
      <bar type="bad">Bad</bar>
    </baz>
  </foo>
}
```

This is the code of the test:

```
it should "allow use of map and filter" in {
  import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

  val expected = ArrayBuffer(
    (
      "bar",
      Map(
        "type" -> "greet",
        "style" -> "pleasent",
        "target" -> "anyone"
      ),
      "hi"
    ),
    (
      "bar",
      Map("type" -> "count"),
      "1"
    ),
    (
      "bar",
      Map("type" -> "color"),
      "yellow"
    )
  )

  val result = foo.child.map(x => {
    x match {
      case <bar>{text}</bar> => (x.label, x.attributes.asAttrMap, text)
      case <baz>_</baz> => (x.label, Map[String,String](), "")
      case _ => ("", Map[String,String](), "")
    }
  })
  .filter(x => {
    x match {
      case ("bar", _, _) => true
      case _ => false
    }
  })


  result.toString should be(expected.toString) // works
 // result should contain allElementsOf expected // fails
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure of what the question is. :)

Comment: I want to know what the appropriate assertion to use here and why my assertion is failing. My source code is **[here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/scalaexercises/blob/master/src/test/scala/example/XmlSpec.scala#L262)** . Could it be because I use `OptionValues` trait of scalatest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of elements in the collections you are comparing are different:

- `result` contains elements of type `(String, Map[String, String], Object)`
- `expected` contains elements of type `(String, Map[String, String], String)`

They might have the same `toString` representation, but that doesn't mean they are equal. The type of `result` is probably not what you expected from this pattern match:

```
x match {
  case <bar>{text}</bar> => (x.label, x.attributes.asAttrMap, text)
  case <baz>_</baz> => (x.label, Map[String,String](), "")
  case _ => ("", Map[String,String](), "")
}
```

Here `text` is of type `xml.Node`. If you want to extract the contents of the node you can use `text.text` which also makes the test pass.

Aside: Recently there was a PR merged to Scala to issue a warning when the `Object` type is inferred ([scala/scala#6178](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6178)), because it's usually a programmer error.